# Polymorphism concept in java

Tags: java, polymorphism

Is there any difference for below code

1. AbstractClass object = new SubClass();(SubClass is a class that extended the AbstractClass)
2. SubClass object = new SubClass();

In both the scenarios subclass extended the Abstract Class and implemented the methods of Abstract Class

Comment: no difference, i find

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels:  This question isn't asking about an interface.

Comment: @Makoto: true, but the concept is the same. And regardless, this question has been asked so often, and it is quite surprising that the OP didn't find the duplicate before posting.

Comment: @Makoto But the principle to _code to an interface_ is the same for abstract classes. In fact, you could exchange "interface" with "most general type in the type hierarchy", couldn't you?

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose:  If the OP were asking, "Why should I...?", then yes, this would be a suitable duplicate.  However, there is an acute difference when working with a concrete and abstract class (especially if the concrete instance has implemented other methods).

Answer (score 1):

The first one is preferred: you're declaring a variable of a more general type, and if the need arises, you could *polymorphically* substitute it for another object instance as long as it also extends from the same abstract class.

In the GoF book they state this principle as "Program to an interface, not an implementation" (technically `AbstractClass` isn't an interface, it's an abstract class, but the same principle applies.)

Comment: Thank you for clarifying the doubt

Comment: @user2514421 If this answer was helpful for you, please don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it, just click on the check mark to its left ;)